Webview2 how to set openfiledialog directory VB.NET
I have a webview2, I'm browsing a web page where there are forms, I'm automating the insertions into the forms from data present in my database, but when I find an  I don't know how to send it the file, because it doesn't accept the value property. By clicking on the browse button, an openfiledialog opens, but I would like it to open automatically in the custom directory, what should I do? I have no solutions, I would also be fine with intercepting the position of the openfiledialog of webview2.
Thank you
I tried setting the download folder hoping it would also work for opening files but to no avail.
WebView21.CoreWebView2.Profile.DefaultDownloadFolderPath = "C:"
